# Delphi - ListView Question

Tags: delphi, listview, listbox, delphi-2009, delphi-7

Is there a ListView (ListBox) or similar component that allows me to easily drop another component in a specific column.  (Multiple columns)? Like a checkbox, button or drop down list or all the above. (It would be nice to be able to sort via the header also)

If not does anyone know of a resource on how to custom draw something like this?

Thanks

-Brad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out VirtualTreeView at [www.soft-gems.net](http://www.soft-gems.net)

It does virtually everything :-)

Comment: Support! I can't do without VirtualTreeview. Free, Open-source, still actively maintained. But be warned, it's very different to use than the usual gridviews. But when you got it, you love it.

Comment: And when you run into troubles....there are more than enough developers here that are ready to help you to the way of doing things using VirtualTreeView